# Good way to check if a String ends with a Regex String

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a given String ends with a Regular Expression String. I have written the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "wf-008-dam-mv1";
    String regex = "mv(\\d)?$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    if(matcher.find() && matcher.end() == str.length()) {
        System.out.println("Ends with true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ends with false");
    }
}
```

Here the `str` can ends with or without number. Is it a good way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `$` anchor already ensures that the pattern must match at the end, a simple `find` is enough; you don’t need to verify the end of the match. If you prepend your pattern with `.*` you can use `matches` rather than `find` which allows you to remove the entire boilerplate:

```
boolean endsWith="wf-008-dam-mv1".matches(".*mv(\\d)?$");
System.out.println("Ends with "+endsWith);
```

That’s all you need…

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty reasonable way to do it, except that the `matcher.end() == str.length()` check is redundant. The `$` regex anchor already takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

`matcher.find()` does the job for you and no need to check with `matcher.end() == str.length()`

[API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) says

```
If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods
```